# What can be the cause of different permissions inside a fresh Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have the situation that a fresh Docker container leads to different results when executed on different machines.
Specifically the file system permissions are different:

```
docker run --rm my-private-image /bin/sh -c "ls -l /"

...
drwxr-xr-t    2 root     root          4096 Dec 18 23:33 tmp
vs.
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 May 29  2020 tmp
```

The problem exists only recently, when I moved the `/var/lib/docker` directory to another partition. So most likely I screwed it up myself.
I already deleted the image in question to force Docker to fetch it freshly to correct the mistake, but no luck here (it corrected different owners/groups, but not the permissions).

The image in question (I called it `my-private-image`) is based upon `trafex/alpine-nginx-php7`, which is responsible for `/tmp`.

My question now is:

- How/Why does Docker keep the different layers even after I deleted the image?
- And what can I do the rectify the situation?

(I could of course just delete the whole `/var/lib/docker` and reinstall Docker to solve that, but I want to understand Docker's internals better)

Comment: `/tmp` often has a mounted tmpfs directory, and Docker may do this automatically; if you run `docker run --rm my-private-image mount`, does it show something mounted there (in either environment)?  (You do not need the `sh -c` wrapper here.)

Comment: @DavidMaze on the tainted environment there is no output at all. On another machine I have a lot of output, but also nothing for `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick check of the image history, nothing jumps out as modifying `/tmp`, so I'm pretty sure it will be the base layer:

```sh
$ docker history trafex/alpine-nginx-php7                                                                                                                                                                         
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
d03c5e607375   5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  HEALTHCHECK &{["CMD-SHELL…   0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisor…   0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080                  0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY --chown=nobodydir:922…   58B       
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /var/www/html         0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  USER nobody                  0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/h…   1.15kB    
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /var/www/html               0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:12908bc96c18db8f…   459B      
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:ba2b24ac43720041…   27B       
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:791d5f77ccca3899…   2.16kB    
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:e7e19bb0340c77dd…   2.91kB    
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/bin/php8 /usr/bin/php     13B       
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c apk --no-cache add   curl   nginx…   121MB     
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL Description=Lightwe…   0B        
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL Maintainer=Tim de P…   0B        
<missing>      6 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B        
<missing>      6 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:f278386b0cef68136…   5.6MB
```

Inspecting the image, that sha looks like the 72e8... layer:

```json
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:72e830a4dff5f0d5225cdc0a320e85ab1ce06ea5673acfe8d83a7645cbd0e9cf",
                "sha256:8e1de91f5d76729f122777c082e5a0a04bf157438b40223add6e5b0d74974b4a",
                "sha256:02bef6095ce13955a5feda9394ceb41e3ff06b1547c179550495f0ea51fa7d81",
                "sha256:3dc8fd1f904d7ed46a9ef40a6083f7da2dd76c5d33acbfe5b49a57054a7e691a",
                "sha256:5e1da4b6ee09de869cc02ebd7b0ef093da7b1b3cf5e1a5258398960679252d1d",
                "sha256:3c93b50985ab6d6ff15f51828432c04d0163232e46d510131ce6fafb44832da9",
                "sha256:4da6c12a08b014c74acc2348d4e5fec101a10f27caf2ac2cd80596c1775cd6ad",
                "sha256:f44b520b457aa8b531c86e63f2c9c391d73f5eca898e698713c679b684637890",
                "sha256:a7a1e7d3913b5bd1b0d13653840349ce407c81beec236055edab400c5a1a0096",
                "sha256:e68f2db5551b5b4c15ad89dae5ee54ea4a3b864c71475146cedfda1ee6d75ec7"
            ]
        },
```

In docker, those are currently stored within `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb` and that has a pointer to the overlay2 folder:

```sh
# cat image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/72e830a4dff5f0d5225cdc0a320e85ab1ce06ea5673acfe8d83a7645cbd0e9cf/cache-id 
a2cd81767ad8c4e1fc556585df7f9904089e4d3884304f1c3a343c234b9a8f08

# ls -al overlay2/a2cd81767ad8c4e1fc556585df7f9904089e4d3884304f1c3a343c234b9a8f08/diff/tmp
total 8
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 Jun 15  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Jul  7 15:51 ..
```

If your filesystem has been corrupted at this level in the move, I'd personally delete the copy (the entire `/var/lib/docker` directory, not just pieces from it) and start over. Docker will not pull layers that it already has locally, and you are probably seeing just the first issue with the /tmp folder permissions.

Comment: Just one question here: Why did you choose `72e8...`? Because it is the first one? - Is there a way, to find out, which `docker history` line corresponds to which layer sha256?

Comment: @theHacker they're in order, the manifest lists them oldest to newest, and docker history does the reverse.